# One Session Factory for the lifetime of an application or one Session Factory per Unit of Work?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, nhibernate

Please see the code below, which creates a Session Factory per Unit Of Work:

```
public int Update(IdentityRoleView role)
        {
           var role2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IdentityRole>(role);

            ISessionFactory SessionFactory = NHConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
            using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Update(role2);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            return 1;
        }
```

It was recently criticized because it means a SessionFactory is created for every unit of work and this is expensive.  With NHibernate; are you supposed to create one SessionFactory for the lifetime of the application in a static variable?

Comment: Create new session for each .. session. How difficult is that to understand?

Comment: @Euphoric, the question says: "One Session Factory per session".  Why is that difficult to understand?

Comment: @Euphoric: the question is about the lifetime of the factory, not about the lifetime of the sessions.

Comment: @DocBrown Oh, right. Never mind then. Yeah. There should only be one factory for whole application.

Comment: @Doc Brown, Say I have three databases i.e. CQRS Read; CQRS Write and ASP.NET Identity. Then would I have one session factory per database instead of one SessionFactory per application?

Comment: @w0051977: I am not an expert on hibernate, but a short look into the docs tells me the `openSession` method of the factory has a connection parameter. So if your three databases do not require different constructor parameters for [SessionFactoryImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl.html), but only 3 different connections, one factory will be enough. However, if they require different constructor parameters, there will be also 3 different factories needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be best to have a single SessionFactory for the entire lifetime of your application, typically created in the ApplicationStart method. The SessionFactory is a very heavy object. It is also thread safe so no worries there.

See the offcial doc at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html 
or at 
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the hyperlinks - very helpful.  Say I have three databases i.e. CQRS Read; CQRS Write and ASP.NET Identity.  Then would I have one session factory per database instead of one SessionFactory per application?

Comment: @w0051977 yes that is correct. You have as many SessionFactories as Databases used in your application but only a single instance of each.